# Can I implement localization manually in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, localization

I have implemented localization in my iphone app to support four language English, French, German and Spanish. So when app starts, it detects local language of device and if it is one out of four of them, it converts the app to local language otherwise it supports base language i.e. English. Requirement of app is that user can select and change language from settings of app, not the device, so app language should not be dependent on device local language. It it possible? If yes, then how to do that? please suggest me.

Comment: you can do this using `HMLocalization` you can find the demo code from github using following link https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMLocalization

Answer (score 3):

Let's try:

```
NSString* NSCustomLocalizedString( NSString *key , NSString *comment)
{
NSString *rs = nil;

// replace [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:KEY_LANGUAGE ] with your language dectection.
if( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:KEY_LANGUAGE ] == e_language_japanese)
{
    rs = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(key,@"Localizable.strings-ja",nil);
}
else
{
    rs = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(key,@"Localizable.strings-en",nil);
}
return rs;
}
```